# Powershell script for SharePoint 2010 Site usage analytics

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, powershell, web-analytics, site-usage

I am trying to figure out powershell commands for SharePoint 2010

TO Analyze Subsite level information

1. When was each subsite last modified
2. WHen was each subsite last updated
3. No. of users for each subsite
4. No. of hits on each subsite

And other uselful information to analyze all the content of the site collection, specifically each subsite within.

Comment: check this if it is helpful: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-SharePoint-Web-19cd2137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a demo below.

```
$Site=Get-SPSite http://sp


 foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
                         $siteUrl = $web.Url
                         $siteName = $web.Title
                         $siteUserCnt = $web.AllUsers.Count
                         $siteusage = $site.Usage.Storage/1MB
                         $Hits = $site.Usage.Hits                       
                         $Created = [datetime]$web.Created
                         $LastModified = $Web.LastItemModifiedDate
                         $SnapShot = (get-date)
                         $LastUpdate = ($SnapShot – [datetime]$LastModified)

                         $outputToCSV = New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Site Title" = $siteName
                         "Url" = $siteUrl
                         "Total Users" =$siteUserCnt
                         "Size" = $siteusage
                         "Date Last Modified" = $LastModified
                         "Days Last Update" = $LastUpdate
                         "Hits" =$Hits
                         "Date Created" =$Created
                           }

                            $outputToCSV | out-file -FilePath "C:\test\test2.csv" -Append



                }
```

The result as below:
 [image]

More reference:
[Powershell script for SharePoint 2010 & SharePoint 2007 Site Usage report.](https://santoshksp.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/powershell-script-for-sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-2007-site-usage-report/)

Comment: this is not giving size of subsite.  $site.Usage.Storage gives size of sitecollection. I have a requirement to get size of each subsites also.